# Get paragraph text inside an element

Tags: javascript, html, paragraph

I want to have the text value from a    `<p>` inside a    `<li>` element.

*html*:

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="myfunction()">
    <span></span>
    <p>This Text</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*javascript*:

```
function myfunction() {
  var TextInsideLi = [the result of this has to be the text inside the paragraph"];
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also pass the li element itself to your myfunction function as shown:

```
function myfunction(ctrl) {
  var TextInsideLi = ctrl.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
}
```

and in your HTML, `<li onclick="myfunction(this)">`

Comment: Thanks, a a little bit simpler then the answer by Engineer ;)

Answer (score 16):

Do you use jQuery? A good option would be

```
text = $('p').text();
```

Comment: I'm assuming there is more than one `<p>` on the page.

Comment: Yeah it was just an example, use any CSS selector for this - just be more specific

Answer (score 15):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Where to JavaScript</title>
    <!-- JavaScript in head tag-->
    <script>
        function changeHtmlContent() {
            var content = document.getElementById('content').textContent;
            alert(content);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4 id="content">Welcome to JavaScript!</h4>
    <button onclick="changeHtmlContent()">Change the content</button>
</body>
```

Here, we can get the text content of `h4` by using:

```
document.getElementById('content').textContent
```

Comment: This answer deserves to be the correct one. So simple and elegant, and doesn't rely on figuring out p tags.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<li onclick="myfunction(this)">

function myfunction(li) {
    var TextInsideLi = li.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WFZ7C/)

Answer (score 6):

change your html to the following:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="myfunction()">
        <span></span>
        <p id="myParagraph">This Text</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

then you can get the content of your paragraph with the following function:

```
function getContent() {
    return document.getElementById("myParagraph").innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
$("li").find("p").html()
```

should work.

Comment: re-invent the wheel by writing a ton of code which will handle the way the DOM works on all different browers.

Comment: I'm assuming there is more than one `<li>` on the page.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="myfunction(this)">
    <span></span>
    <p>This Text</p>
  </li>
</ul>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function myfunction(foo) {
    var elem = foo.getElementsByTagName('p');
    var TextInsideLi = elem[0].innerHTML;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use eg. "id" you can do it this way:

```js
   (function() {
    let x = document.getElementById("idName");
    let y = document.getElementById("liName");
    
    y.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        y.appendChild(x);
    });

  
})();
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <p id="idName">TEXT</p>
    <ul>
        <li id="liName">

        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script src="js/scripts/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `Id` property into the `P` tag with value like text or something:

```
function gettext() {
    var amount = document.getElementById('text').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const copyLink = () => {
   console.log('btn click');
   let linkURL = document.getElementById('clipboard').innerText;

}
```

In p tag:

```
<p id="clipboard" class="px-1 sm:px-8 py-4 ">
    {`https://offerstreet.in/coupons/coupon/?asin=${asin}`} 
</p>
```